# Function devolver valores

Tags: php

Estoy intentado incluir un código en function para que sea más optimo pero no consigo visualizar los valores el código en cuestión es este.

```
    function Ciudad() {
     if ($Datos[0]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte = " Ciudad, ";}
     if ($Datos[1]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad2, ";}
     if ($Datos[2]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad3, ";}
     if ($Datos[3]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad4, ";}
     if ($Datos[4]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad5, ";}
     if ($Datos[5]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad6, ";}
     if ($Datos[6]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad7, ";}
     if ($Datos[7]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad8, ";}
     if ($Datos[8]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad9, ";}
     if ($Datos[9]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad10, ";}
     if ($Datos[10]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad11, ";}
     if ($Datos[11]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad12, ";}
     if ($Datos[12]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad13, ";}
     if ($Datos[13]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad14, ";}
     if ($Datos[14]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad15, ";}
     if ($Datos[15]["Valor1"]>10) {$txte .= "Ciudad16";}
     return $txte;
    }
```

Al Igual he pensado optimizarlo dado que los valores los saco de $Datos[0]["Valor1"] y la ciudad de $Datos[0]["Nombre"] había pensado en un bucle que juntase la información que cumpla con el requisito de > 10 algo así...

```
    function Ciudad($id, $valor) {
    for ($i = $id; $i <  16; $i++) { 
        for ($j = $valor; $j < 17; $j++) { 
            if ($Datos[$i]["Valor".($j)]>10) {
            $ciudades .= $Datos[$i]["Nombre"]; } }
    }
     return $ciudades;
    }
```

Comment: Necesitas acceder al Array de datos dentro de la función, puedes pasarlo como parámetro o acceder a él como variable global. Una duda, accedes al valor siempre con "Valor 1" o es variable?

Comment: @Carmen cómo podría hacer eso? Es variable el Valor 1 por eso en el código lo puse como $Datos[$i]["Valor".($j)]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Cuando veo código como el tuyo la primera palabra que se me ocurre es justo una que mencionas en la pregunta:  ***Optimizar***. Tu código necesita ciertamente una optimización seria, pero si no se conoce bien el contexto es imposible sugerir algo que resuelva el problema de raíz. A veces para optimizar hay que retroceder, mejorando por ejemplo la forma en que se construye el objeto `$Datos`, o aún mucho más,  porque  a veces hay que optimizar incluso el origen mismo de los datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que en cuanto a optimizar con el código que estoy mencionado se está optimizando primero lo trabajo a lo brusco y después optimizo cuando funciona la cuestión es que al no saber donde falla no podía seguir.

Comment: No sé. Por ejemplo la comparación `> 10` me hace dudar sobre tal optimización. Como ya dije, sin conocer el contexto opinar sobre optimización es aventurarse. Pero, imaginemos un contexto donde sólo necesitas la información para esto, y que los datos vienen de una base de datos (o de otra fuente). Si sólo necesitas los que son mayor que 10, y traes todos los datos para luego desechar una parte, el código no está optimizado. Es un ejemplo que pongo para decir que, en un contexto como ese tu código no está optimizado porque traes datos sin filtrar para hacerlo luego, pudiéndolo hacer antes.

Comment: A mi todo lo que es crear valores o variables con números como `Ciudad1, Ciudad2, Ciudad3...` me suena a un gravísimo error de concepción, de diseño, de lógica a veces a un nivel muy profundo... Te preguntaría, ¿a qué se debe que tengas que concatenar valores de esa forma? ¿para qué utilidad o finalidad? ¿no se podría hacer de otro modo más **óptimo** y además más *elegante*?

Comment: @A.Cedano Traigo todos los datos al array ya que posteriormente son utilizados, solo que en esta parte necesito filtrar aún más  para sacar solo esos valores.

Y si son obtenidos de la base de datos.

Comment: Bueno yo sólo intento hacer una crítica constructiva porque me da la impresión de que realmente el código no está optimizado. Pero dejemos eso y nos centramos en el problema. Sería bueno que muestres un pequeño trozo de la constitución de `$Datos`,  indicando un ejemplo del resultado final que esperas obtener.

Comment: Si entiendo tu critica, tampoco tengo los conocimientos tan elevados como para poder optimizarlo al 100% ahí lo voy intentando.

$Datos se obtiene de while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ $Datos[]=$row; } $result->close();  El cual es almacenado para su uso el cual le estoy dando. La cuestión es que tengo por ejemplo $Datos[0][Valor1] que da un valor superior a 10 por eso ahí lo filtro con > 10 y después lo vinculo a $Datos[0][Nombre] para sacar la Ciudad la cuestión es sacar los valores de Valor1, Valor2 y demás para obtener Ciudades: x1, x2, x3 y así...

Comment: La cuestión es que puedes aplicar funciones al mismo array para determinar si el valor `x` de la clave `y` es mayor a `10` y hacer lo que quieras en consecuencia. Pero para todo eso se necesita ver un pequeño ejemplo de la estructura de los datos. Eso se puede hacer con dos o tres líneas de código usando alguna de las funciones para arrays de que dispone PHP. Si muestras una estructura real de los datos y lo que quieres se te puede ayudar mejor, sin tener que partir necesariamente de una solución no optimizada.

Answer (score 0):

Le puedes pasar tus datos como parámetro. He declarado la variable que retornas en vacío para que siempre sea accesible aunque no se encuentren datos para añadir.

```
$Datos[0]["Valor1"]=3;
$Datos[0]["Nombre"]="Pekin";
$Datos[0]["Valor2"]=13;
$Datos[0]["Nombre"]="Tokio";
$Datos[1]["Valor1"]=3;
$Datos[1]["Nombre"]="Londres";
$Datos[1]["Valor2"]=13;
$Datos[1]["Nombre"]="Paris";

echo Ciudad(0,1,$Datos);
echo "<br>";
echo Ciudad(1,1,$Datos);

function Ciudad($id, $valor,$Datos) {
   $ciudades ="";
   for ($i = $id; $i < 2; $i++) { 
            for ($j = $valor; $j < 3; $j++) { 
                if ($Datos[$i]["Valor".$j]>10) {
                $ciudades .= $Datos[$i]["Nombre"]; } 
            }
  }
  return $ciudades;
}
```

Resultado:

```
TokioParis
Paris
```

Comment: Lo he probado y no consigo mostrar los valores hecho var_dump y me sale string 0

Comment: @Vicente lo he probado y funciona, edito con un ejemplo completo. Comprueba los parámetros que pasas a la función.

Comment: Creo que lo que el OP necesita se puede hacer con dos o tres líneas de código con alguna función como `array_map` combinada con otra si fuera necesario. Pero en el planteamiento no se explica con claridad lo que necesita ni cómo está estructurado el array internamente. Tu solución, en caso de que funcione, sería un parche no optimizado a una solución del problema planteada también de una forma no óptima.

Comment: @A.Cedano es muy posible que se pueda hacer de otros modos, pero pregunta por qué no le resulta convertir el código a función, y el uso de bucles es una buena simplificación de código. Cambiar el planteamiento puede ser interesante, pero sería una cuestión diferente.

Comment: También es cierto Carmen, sería otro planteamiento. Aunque al menos yo me permito comentar solo para indicar que existen ciertas funciones que ayudan a simplificar aún más las cosas. En algunas preguntas se puede dar una solución basada en el código original, pero también mostrar otras posibles vías  de solución más simples. Claro que pasar de un bucle a todos los `if` iniciales ya es un gran paso. Saludos.

Comment: @Carmen vale no había quitado el cóodigo anterior por eso era le he metido un añadido para la separación $ciudades .= $Datos[$i]["Nombre"].", "; pero ahora no veo una forma de quitárselo a la ultima palabra ó remplazarselo por un punto ya que lo interpreta en general sabrías como podría hacerlo he probado con $ciudades = substr ($ciudades, 0, -2); pero lo interpreta en general seria pasarlo a otra variable supongo.

Comment: @A.Cedano así es amigo es un paso, no busco la perfección ni mucho menos sería pedir mucha más requerir vuestra ayuda y supongo que con el tiempo podré ir puliéndolo. Y los If es un simple código de ver una idea después es perfeccionarla  en ningún caso lo dejaría tan sucio por eso intento pulir poco a poco si no tendría ahora mismo un archivo muy extenso.

Comment: @Vicente para quitar en todos los casos el último carácter de la cadena resultante lo puedes hacer con echo substr(Ciudad(0,1,$Datos), 0, -1);

Comment: Si lo que necesitas son valores separados por comas, puedes crear un array aparte con esos valores y luego usar `implode`.

Comment: @Carmen será error mio o del código que hice pero el problema es que Valo1 y Valor2 no deberían mezclarse  y he probado tu modificación a simple vista va bien cuando le metes más valores se mezclan. Solo incrementando el valor $Datos[0]["Valor1"]=33;
$Datos[0]["Nombre"]="Pekin";
$Datos[0]["Valor2"]=33;
$Datos[0]["Nombre"]="Tokio";
$Datos[1]["Valor1"]=33;
$Datos[1]["Nombre"]="Londres";
$Datos[1]["Valor2"]=33;
$Datos[1]["Nombre"]="Paris";

Comment: @Vicente Es por el diseño del array, a Valor1 debería corresponderle Nombre1 y a Valor2  Nombre2, de modo que también tendrías que usar el índice $j para extraer el nombre

Comment: @Carmen perdón por no haber contestado antes me surgieron problemas como asi porque es problema del array? en teoría con [1],[2] debería interpretarlo bien no?

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente código se crea un array tomando el valor de la clave `Nombre` del array original en los casos en que el valor de la clave `Valor` del mismo array original sea mayor que `10`.

No sé si es exactamente lo que quieres, pero, sea lo que sea, intuyo que es algo que se puede hacer de una forma muy simple según tus requerimientos.

Para imprimir la lista de ciudades separadas por `,`, aplicamos `implode` sobre `$partialData`.

El código incluye un *simulacro* sobre el posible estado original de tu array.

```
$datos=array(
                array("Nombre"=>"Madrid",   "Valor"=>10),
                array("Nombre"=>"Tokio",    "Valor"=>15),
                array("Nombre"=>"New York", "Valor"=>5),
                array("Nombre"=>"París",    "Valor"=>10),
                array("Nombre"=>"Londres",  "Valor"=>11),
                array("Nombre"=>"Berlín",   "Valor"=>3)   
            );

foreach ($datos as $item){
    if ($item["Valor"]>10){
        $partialData[]=$item["Nombre"];
    }
}
echo implode(",",$partialData);
```

**Salida:**

```
Tokio,Londres
```

---

#### EDICIÓN:

Si en cambio el array es así:

```
$datos=array(
                array("Nombre"=>"Madrid",   "Valor1"=>10),
                array("Nombre"=>"Tokio",    "Valor2"=>15),
                array("Nombre"=>"New York", "Valor3"=>5),
                array("Nombre"=>"París",    "Valor4"=>10),
                array("Nombre"=>"Londres",  "Valor5"=>11),
                array("Nombre"=>"Berlín",   "Valor6"=>3)   
            );
```

Sólo hay que implementar un contador para construir el nombre de la clave dinámicamente:

```
$i=1;

foreach ($datos as $item){
    if ($item["Valor$i"]>10){
        $partialData[]=$item["Nombre"];
    }
    $i++;
}
echo implode(",",$partialData);
```

La salida será la misma.  Si también las clave `Nombre` tuviesen un número secuencial, agregas el valor aquí: `$partialData[]=$item["Nombre$i"];`, aunque es una pena que los datos estén así, pudiendo tener un diseño de datos más fácil y estructurado...

---

**NOTA:** Si se trata de algo más complejo, has de saber que PHP cuenta con [varias decenas de funciones sobre arrays](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php) capaces de hacer cualquier tipo de operación complicada de una forma sencilla. Muchas de ellas, combinadas con otras funciones del lenguaje, hacen posible cualquier tipo de comparación, operación, cálculo, construcción de nuevos arrays, etc.

Comment: La cuestión seria poder manipular el valor de las variables Valor no será Valor sera Valor1, Valor2 así lo tengo estructurado son diferentes campos por separado.

Comment: @Vicente en el ejemplo de tu pregunta los campos se llaman todos igual: `Valor`, por eso te pedí una muestra de los datos reales. De todos modos, si los campos tiene **por desgracia o por mal diseño** un nombre incremental, puedes implementar un contador y construir en base a eso el nombre de la clave. Pero, viendo que esos datos vienen de una base de datos, es evidente que tu modelo de datos necesita ser revisado y mejorado. Ahora editaré la respuesta, mostrando una forma de hacerlo con un contador.

Comment: Si mil disculpas no me explique con claridad, los campos son incrementales porqué pensé que sería la forma más básica  si no serian campos con diferentes nombres que van a hacer una funcionalidad guardar valores por separado de ahí a que no deban ser iguales. Para que te hagas una idea Se compone de id, nombre, valor1, valor2, valor3, valor4, valor5, valor6, valor7, valor8, confirmado

Comment: @Vicente viendo que esos datos vienen de una base de datos, me temo que voy a tener razón en lo que te dije hace un rato. Creo que empezaste diseñando mal el mismo modelo de datos (en la base de datos). Da la impresión de que quisiste meter una serie de valores en una sola tabla cuando pudiste haber implementado un modelo relacional que use varias tablas y exprese las relaciones mediante índices. De ese modo, tus columnas no se llamarían `Valor1, Valor2, Valor99999` o `Nombre1, Nombre2, Nombre9999`, sino que se llamarían `Valor` y `Nombre` y tendrías un array asociativo con tus datos ...

Comment: ... incluso ya organizados sin necesidad que tener que recurrir a esto o en caso de tener que recurrir a esto, hacerlo como se indica en la 1ª parte de la respuesta. Como te dije, en cuanto hay algo que se repite al estilo `valor1, valor2, valor3, valor4, valor5, valor6, valor7, valor8` es una clara evidencia de un mal diseño de datos.

Comment: Si lo metí todo en un tabla ya que solo tiene una finalidad que es almacenar el nombre y 8 campos de valores y un campo adicional al estilo de la tabla de un foro ya que todo se consulta ahí, de igual modo de haberlo separado hubiese ido el nombre en otra tabla pero los valores no le vería el sentido que fuesen por separados debido a que van a tener el mismo objetivo. Entiendo que tienes más conocimiento y lo hubieses estructurar de mejor manera pero para mi seria un mundo y necesitaría mayor conocimiento no obstante es aceptable tu critica si sabes por donde comenzar a ver como estructurar...

Comment: @Vicente Realmente no sé a qué se refieren todos esos `valor...`, pero estoy casi seguro que deberían ir en otra tabla por muchos motivos. Pero dejemos eso. Centrándonos en el problema actual: dado que las columnas `valor...` son las mismas y son secuenciales, ¿no te funciona con lo que te he dicho usando el contador? Si no funciona, ¿cuál es la dificultad por la que no funciona o qué datos produce haciéndolo de ese modo?